# How do I create a open folder keyboard shortcut in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2

I know to add keyboard shortcuts, I go into `Keyboard Bindings - User` and edit the JSON file. I already have a lot of keyboard customizations.

```
[
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+."], "command": "erb" },
  { "keys": ["alt+i"], "command": "expand_tabs" },
  { "keys": ["alt+ctrl+w"], "command": "close_all" },
  { "keys": ["ctrl+t"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "goto", "show_files": true} },
  // swap the keybindings for paste and paste_and_indent
  { "keys": ["ctrl+v"], "command": "paste_and_indent" },
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+v"], "command": "paste" },
  // swap the keybindings for save and save_all
  { "keys": ["ctrl+s"], "command": "save_all" },
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+v"], "command": "save" }
]
```

I just need to know the command for open folder. I tried the obvious `open_folder` it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer in the [Sublime Text 2 forums](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/open-folder-keyboard-shortcut/5158). The command is `prompt_open_folder`. So I just added this to my keyboard bindings.

```
[
  // Open folder shortcut
  { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+o"], "command": "prompt_open_folder"}
]
```